How to set Bootstrap 4 column width relative to parent div
I am using Bootstrap 4 and am trying to create a simple layout. Two columns, split into 9 columns and 3 columns. Inside the first column is just text. But I need a padding of 1 column. Not 1 column of the containing div, but one column of the entire page. Here is an example

My code below obviously doesn't work. The 1 column padding is 1 column of the containing div.


.left-box {
    background: lightgray;
    text-align: justify;
}

.right-box {
    background: darkgray;
    height: 100px;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9">
            <div class="left-box py-1">
                <div class="col-10 offset-1">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nec volutpat sapien. Suspendisse erat ex, condimentum et faucibus et, ornare in elit. Mauris eget lacinia sapien. Proin eu porttitor odio.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="right-box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



This gives the following result, where the padding is incorrect.

Is there a way to achieve the correct padding?

Doesn't change much about what I said - your col-10 offset-1 element there is in the right place, but since it itself also has a padding-left, the content of that column still gets moved a bit more to the right than you want.

Thanks @C3roe. But col-10 is not in the right place. If I remove the padding, the texdt will start at the end of the first column (almost). If you look at the first image in my post, I need the text to start at the beginning of the second column

So you want offset-2 then, without any further manipulation of any cell paddings?

No. Then, the offset is way too big. The problem is that the 10 columns is based on the parent div with a class of left-box. Bootstrap breaks that div.left-box into 12 even columns. So the offset will be 2 columns of div.left-box. What I need is a padding of 1 column of the div.container

Can you not simply make the first top-level column 8 wide and offset it by 1 - and eliminate the padding-left in the column as well? Without introducing any additional nested columns inside. https://jsfiddle.net/fstma8nz/

That 8 column div (.left-box) has a background colour. If I just offset that, the background will not start until column 2

Then calculate the necessary padding-left. calc(8.333% + 15px) - 100% / 12 columns gives us the 8.333%, plus the 15px column-gutter. https://jsfiddle.net/e4vjxm13/ Note that I moved the left-box class directly to the column there, and eliminated additional wrapper elements.

That padding worked. Thanks for your help

@C3roe, please post a proper answer so the question can be resolved.

You can calculate the necessary padding-left, calc(8.333% + 15px) - 100% / 12 columns gives us the 8.333%, plus the 15px column-gutter.


.left-box {
    background: lightgray;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-left: calc(8.333% + 15px) !important;
}

.right-box {
    background: darkgray;
    height: 100px;
}

.test .col-1 { height: 1em; outline: 1px solid red; }


.test .col-1 div { outline: 1px solid blue; }
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row test">
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-1"><div>
    foo
    </div></div>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-9 left-box" style="background:#ccc">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nec volutpat sapien. Suspendisse erat ex, condimentum et faucibus et, ornare in elit. Mauris eget lacinia sapien. Proin eu porttitor odio.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="right-box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



